# Are the commas compulsory here?

Tags: grammar

There are many similar sentences, such as:

> On Christmas Eve, townspeople...
>
> After lunch, he often...
>
> One January morning, we were returning from...

Are the commas compulsory here?
Or can they be omitted?

Or where such information can be found?

Comment: The site quickandirtytips.com (Grammar Girl) has [quite a good reputation here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/what-are-we-going-to-ask-grammar-girl). Here's a [page](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-commas-a-summary) with some tips on commas.

Comment: It's a fine page, Lawrence, but I've found nothing concerning my question there.

Comment: Commas make the meaning of sentences clear by grouping and separating words, phrases, and clauses (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/comma). Be consistent how you use commas, and remember that the goal is clarity. That said, people use them differently and there will be some variety due to aesthetics/style.

Comment: Well, Dan, there's nothing useful there either... But, nevertheless, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Victor - I think the point is that YOU have to decide how you want the sentence to be read.  If you want a small gap between words then you should insert a comma, otherwise it will not be clear which words belong together and which are clearer for being separated.

Comment: Dan, I think something else is going on here... Perhaps they indicate the word order breaking in the sentences. I mean the adverbial modifiers of time. Their relocation to the beginning of the sentences...

Comment: Can you summarise how your examples are similar? For example, are you asking about the use of commas after a time reference?

Comment: I mean exactly this similarity, Lawrence - the adverbial modifiers of the time at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: I've looked through many grammar and punctuation websites, reflecting on pauses between parts of sentences, and I can hardly call adverbial modifiers of time as parts of sentences (they haven't got any parts of a sentence inside) which need a special pause after them.

Answer (score 2):

[Purdue Owl](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/03/) suggests that you should not use a comma after an introductory prepositional phrase of fewer than five words. According to this, the commas in your first two examples should be left out.

This length quantification "of fewer than five words" is clearly over-precise. Think of this as a guideline, and use your judgment. Very few people are going to object if you leave out commas on some five-word prepositional phrases, or include them on some three- or four-word phrases.

And note that your last example – *"One January morning"* – isn't a prepositional phrase and, according to *Purdue Owl,* needs the comma.

Comment: Thank you, Peter! That's the very thing I expected to find out!